# How to align elements Horizontally in css?

Tags: html, css

To Be Precise, I have a div which I need to align inner elements horizontally.

As you can see at this Jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/xxcm84x1/ the position of my div inner elements are relative but they are aligned vertically just need to change that to horizontal.

HTML:

```
<div class="firstdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv"></div>
  <span class="firstspan">Align elements Horizontally <----></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.firstdiv{
  position:absolute;
  height:40px;
  width:250px;
  background:white;
}
.innerdiv{
  position:relative;
  height:30px;
  top:5px;
  width:40px;
  background:green;
}
.firstspan{
  position:relative;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Float or flex them?

Comment: span and div cannot be sibblings :( these are inline and block elements . you need to take the basic HTML tutorials. CSS can reset their display properties : https://jsfiddle.net/xxcm84x1/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: flex` on the parent will put the children in a horizontal row.

```css
.firstdiv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
}

.innerdiv {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: green;
}

.firstspan {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv"></div>
  <span class="firstspan">Align elements Horizontally</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @WjNa Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you with your issue.

Comment: don't you think that div and span side by side is a bit odd in the first place ? 101 html tuorials should be advised also here :)